# Buttons not firing of async postback in update panel

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a problem with buttons firing a full postback in a updatepanel, and i just cannot figure out why.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div class="VidVote">
    <ul class='star-rating'>
        <asp:Panel ID="CurrRate" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        <li><asp:Button ID="OneCati" CssClass="one-star" runat="server" 
            onclick="OneCati_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></li>
        <li><asp:Button ID="TwoCati" CssClass="two-stars" runat="server" 
            onclick="TwoCati_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></li>
        <li><asp:Button ID="ThreeCati" CssClass="three-stars" runat="server" 
            onclick="ThreeCati_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></li>
        <li><asp:Button ID="FourCati" CssClass="four-stars" runat="server" 
            onclick="FourCati_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></li>
        <li><asp:Button ID="FiveCati" CssClass="five-stars" runat="server" 
            onclick="FiveCati_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="OneCati" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TwoCati" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ThreeCati" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FourCati" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FiveCati" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div class="VidScore">
    <h3 style='text-align:center;margin-bottom:0; font-size:40px;'>
        <asp:Label ID="Score" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </h3>
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

i have tried with every combination of panels i can think of and without asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger

noticed 
http://finalfantasyworld.net/dev/Movie/ Works
http://dev.finalfantasyworld.net/Movie/ don't work

see the problem in action http://dev.finalfantasyworld.net/Movie/ try the rating

Comment: Your buttons need to be in the same `UpdatePanel` that defines the post-back triggers. You might be able to get away with setting the `ChildrenAsTriggers` property to true on your first `UpdatePanel` without explicitly defining the triggers.

Comment: Il change the code a little, as the problem is still there after fixing what you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your async triggers in updatepanel2 and remove updatepanel1 and put that all button outside of update panel, only your lable section should be in updatepanle2. let me know your result..

Comment: If you are doing form authentication and you have denied authorization
of resources then APP_Theme also denied for anonymous user..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing something like this?:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline"> 
    <Triggers> 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="OneCati" EventName="Click" /> 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TwoCati" EventName="Click" /> 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ThreeCati" EventName="Click" /> 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FourCati" EventName="Click" /> 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FiveCati" EventName="Click" /> 
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <div class="VidVote"> 
        <ul class='star-rating'> 
            <asp:Panel ID="CurrRate" runat="server"></asp:Panel> 
            <li><asp:Button ID="OneCati" CssClass="one-star" runat="server"  
                onclick="OneCati_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></li> 
            <li><asp:Button ID="TwoCati" CssClass="two-stars" runat="server"  
                onclick="TwoCati_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></li> 
            <li><asp:Button ID="ThreeCati" CssClass="three-stars" runat="server"  
                onclick="ThreeCati_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></li> 
            <li><asp:Button ID="FourCati" CssClass="four-stars" runat="server"  
                onclick="FourCati_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></li> 
            <li><asp:Button ID="FiveCati" CssClass="five-stars" runat="server"  
                onclick="FiveCati_Click" CausesValidation="False" /></li> 
        </ul> 
        </div> 
        <div class="VidScore"> 
            <h3 style='text-align:center;margin-bottom:0; font-size:40px;'> 
                <asp:Label ID="Score" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> 
            </h3> 
        </div> 
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: hehe "my what?" i only use the ScriptManager plain with EnablePartialRendering="true", which usualy work. and its placed on the masterpage if thats usual information, (no change if i move it to the page in use)

Comment: Try my example above, but remove the triggers completely. If no triggers are specified, it will assume that everything in the update panel is ajaxified.

Comment: Just noticed. Try changing `UpdateMode` to "Always"

Comment: still don't work,
Just noticed something
http://finalfantasyworld.net/dev/Movie/ Works
http://dev.finalfantasyworld.net/Movie/ don't work

Comment: Running out of ideas here, but can you replace the single quotes around style attributes to double-quotes? For example `<ul style='star-rating'>`

Comment: no change i gueass il just have to use /dev folder instead of the dev. subdomain

Comment: What version of .NET are you using, and what version is selected under the ASP.NET tab in IIS?

Comment: Ive used what ever is native on VS10 Ultimate with SP1 and IIS7 so i gueas everything should be up to snuff.